# How to effectively pass a multi-choice SSRS 2008 parameter to a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, ssrs-2008

I have a report in SSRS 2008 R2 / BIDS.
One of the parameters is a multi-select text for, let's say, names, which I get the values from a stored procedure. The user selects one or more of these values.

I then call another stored procedure to get the data for the report, and I pass the parameter with the names selected as a parameter to the stored procedure, `@p_names`.

In that stored procedure, I select the records `WHERE CHARINDEX(fName,@p_names) > 0`. In other words, where I find that the first name for the record is in the parameter string.

The obvious problem is that, if for example, the values are:

And the user selects

> - Joe
> - Mary
> - Mary Joe
> - Edward
> - Cindy

Then my `CHARINDEX` selection will return Joe, Mary, Mary Joe and Edward, when the used only wanted Mary Joe and Edward.

> - Mary Joe
> - Edward

How should I pass the multichoice parameter to the stored procedure and how should I structure my `WHERE` clause?

Thanks.

Comment: Muhammed Ali, I wouldn't want to start a boxing match with you... but the post is less readable now, I think.

Comment: Neither am I a boxer :) ,But its a comman practice to make you `Data` or `Code` stand out from your text in your question. thats all :)

Comment: Regarding the data you are absolutely right. Thanks for that. I'll keep that in mind going forward. I was referring that "And the user selects" should go right before the 2 data items and "Then my CHARINDEX selection will return..." should go after the 2 data items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for exact matches without having to split:

```
WHERE CHARINDEX(',' + fName + ',',',' + @p_names + ',') > 0
```

However, if you have large lists it may have better performance using the split method.

Comment: This is perfect. After I asked the question I found a similar approach myself, but I was wrapping @p_names with ',' in BIDS. I didn't think of your approach with is to do everything in the SP. Much better. I'll change mine. Great.

Answer (score 2):

> Right Amarundo there is no easy solution for this , when you allow
>   Multiple values to be passed to your Report Parameter, It actually
>   passes a Comma Deliminated string of them values to your DataSet Query/Stored Procedure.
>
> To
>   Make it work you will need two thing
>
> 1) Create a Function which
>   accepts a  Comma Deliminated string and split them.
>
> 2) Modify you
>   Store Procedure and add this function in there in a way that passed
>   parameter is passed to the function inside that store procedure and
>   that function split the values before passing it onto your store
>   Procedure .

Create this function 1st

**Function Definition**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[FnSplit]
(
@List nvarchar(2000),
@SplitOn nvarchar(5)
)
RETURNS @RtnValue table (Id int identity(1,1), Value nvarchar(100))
AS
BEGIN

WHILE(Charindex(@SplitOn,@List)>0)

  BEGIN


        INSERT INTO @RtnValue (value)

        SELECT VALUE = ltrim(rtrim(Substring(@List,1,Charindex(@SplitOn,@List)-1)))

        SET @List = SUBSTRING(@List,Charindex(@SplitOn,@List)+len(@SplitOn),len(@List))

  END


INSERT INTO @RtnValue (Value)

SELECT VALUE = ltrim(rtrim(@List))

RETURN

END
```

**Modify you strored Procedure something like this**

**Stored Procedure**

```
CREATE Procedure usp_Multipleparameter (@Param1 VARCHAR(1000)= NULL)
AS
BEGIN

        SELECT * FROM TableName
        where ColumnNAME  IN (SELECT Value FROM dbo.FnSplit(@Param1,','))

END
GO
```